# How do I get and print value of an environment variable?

Tags: windows, console, environment-variables, echo, nmake

I want to print value from a Windows environment variable, say, path or errorlevel, I've tried [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99at5bh3.aspx) but it doesn't work. Output this in my console:

*(without consider spaces/tabs which it outputs):*

```
echo %PATH
%PATH
```

**Makefile:**

```
PATH=$(PATH);\nonesuch

all:
    echo %PATH%
```

**command-line:**

```
nmake /E
```

How do I fix it?

*NOTE: Visual Studio's binary path is in my PATH variable, that's why I'm calling this outside VS console*

Comment: set [name] as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910900/how-do-i-get-and-print-value-of-an-environment-variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The percent sign `%` has special meaning in Makefiles.

In order to perform the Windows batch-file substitution, you need to escape it like this:

```
echo %%PATH%%
```

This seems to work too:

```
"echo %PATH%"
```

---

Another option is to perform the substitution on the Make side, but that's a different thing:

```
echo $(PATH)
```

Comment: It did worked fine for PATH variable but not to errorlevel. What's wrong with that? echo %%ERRORLEVEL%%

Comment: ERRORLEVEL is not an actual environment variable.  The fact that %ERRORLEVEL% resolves to the most recent error level in a batch file is a special feature of the batch processor.

Comment: You literally saved my wife! Thanks!

Comment: @NoName Sounds serious – I'm glad your marriage is OK ;-)

Answer (score -3):

To view your path, just try out this

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: That's for bash only